# Asus Usb AC51 Can't contact

Tags: wireless, asus, ralink

I tried Asus USB ac 51 with driver which is in the CD on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS ,but I got error 2

After that, I used the driver
https://github.com/likwidoxigen/mt7610u_wifi
,and I got a Can't use message in networks 
.

I can use iwconfig find ra0 this device,but just can't use .

How to fix it??